# htaccess rewrite avoid all files but .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]*)/(?:(.*)?)$ ?page=$1 [L] [QSA]
```

I use this to pass the name of the page to the PHP script. 
This works if I use

```
http://host.com/news/whatever/
```

but it doesn't with

```
http://host.com/news/whatever/index.php
```

so how can skip all files (css, png etc) but still allow .php?

Comment: `!-f` anti-matches any files which actually exist. if you really do have a `/news/whatever/index.php`, then !-f will prevent the rules from kicking in.

Comment: If I remove that or only exclude particular extensions it redirects everything to the homepage (still sends the "page" query string though)

Comment: @SandroAntonucci what is the URL you want to input and what is the URL outcome you want? I'm not clear what it is you need. You only want pages that end in PHP to use that rule?

Answer (score 1):

> `so how can skip all files (css, png etc) but still allow .php?`

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```